# iOS Bluetooth connection

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, bluetooth

If I had an app running on  iPhone/iPad that is about to open a connection with a Bluetooth device.   Before it opens this connection, could it check to see if any other app running has a connection open with that same Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. Bluetooth can only search for other nearby devices, not other nearby connections.

But,

If you are using External Accessory Framework and MFI enrolled accessories, EAAccessoryManager has a [connectedAccessories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessoryManager_class/Reference/Reference.html) method which returns a list of all accessories connected to the device which can be used by the Application.

> **connectedAccessories**
>
> The accessory objects corresponding to the list of currently connected
>   accessories. (read-only)
>
> ```
> @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *connectedAccessories;
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> > This property contains an array of EAAccessory objects. Each object
> >     corresponds to an accessory that is connected and available for your
> >     application to use. Because the contents of this property can change
> >     dynamically based on the connection and disconnection of accessories,
> >     you should not cache the value of this property.

This is your best bet in finding connected accessories. I don't know whether this will help in your case.

Comment: Is this the same from 'not other nearby connections' but other connections coming from the same iPhone/iPad?